# Could not transfer artifact - not authorized

Tags: maven, repository, authorization

I want to use an artifact "eu.excitementproject:lap:jar:1.1.0:" from the following repository:

```
http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/eu/excitementproject
```

I can download the jar directly from the above link without any authorization.

However, when I mvn install on my computer, I get the following error:

```
Could not transfer artifact eu.excitementproject:lap:pom:1.1.0 from/to excitement 
(http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/eu/excitementproject): 
Not authorized
```

Here is the relevant part of my pom.xml:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>excitement</id>
      <name>excitement</name>
      <url>http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/eu/excitementproject</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.excitementproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>lap</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is there a proxy server preventing you from accessing that link from Maven? Perhaps you have a proxy configured in your browser settings - which is why you can access the link without authorization. If so, you'll need to configure the proxy in your `settings.xml`

Comment: I don't have any proxy in my browser. I don't have problems accessing any other repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Maven configuration is:

1. repository URL - `http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/eu/excitementproject`
2. group-id - `eu.excitementproject`
3. artifact-id - `lap`
4. artifact-version - `1.1.1`.

The full path to the artifact is therefore `http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/eu/excitementproject/eu.excitementproject/lap/1.1.1/lap-1.1.1.pom`.

If I hit [this URL](http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/eu/excitementproject/eu.excitementproject/lap/1.1.1/lap-1.1.1.pom) from any web browser, I am asked to authenticate using basic HTTP authentication.  This is exactly what Maven also sees.  Therefore, as @Will mentioned above, if you wish to continue using this repository URL, you will have to configure authentication settings for the repository in your local settings.xml.

Interestingly, I can hit `http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/eu.excitementproject/lap/1.1.1/lap-1.1.1.pom` without problems.  So, if you shorten your repository URL to `http://hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo`, your build will work (I have tested this).

Comment: Thanks! So the problem was in my repository URL.

Answer (score 4):

you can provide credentials to your artifactory using basic url authentification(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basic_access_authentication). 
In your case repository url should be:
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@hlt-services4.fbk.eu:8080/artifactory/repo/eu/excitementproject